# I am using struts2 application but its asking the spring configuration

Tags: struts2

I am getting the following error when i am trying to run the manning examples separately out of the sand box.

Error as follows:

```
You might need to add the following to web.xml: 
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

Jun 17, 2013 7:17:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.getClassInstance(SpringObjectFactory.java:188)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyResultType(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:479)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addResultTypes(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:407)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:152)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
            <param-value>manning</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>anotherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>manning.servlet.AnotherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>anotherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/anotherServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

   <!--
            For the purposes of the book, we will leave devMode set to true.  This
            allows several things to occur including provision of debugging level information
            on error pages as well as reloading of various resources with each request.
   --> 
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
        <!-- 
            You can define packages directly in this file, but its probably best
            to modularize the configuration files with separate xml files for each
            package.  Ulitmately its all the same because the include element, seen
            below, pulls the included configuration document directly in to the 
            primary document.  The only thing to consider is that a referenced
            element must have been declared above the referring element.         
        -->

        <!-- 
                This is the menu action that will allow the reader to see the different
                samples actions from the different chapters in a menu format.  We declare
                it here, in the root namespace, because its not really related to any of the
                specific examples or chapters, its just a kind of utility for the whole 
                application.
        -->
        <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"> 
            <action name="Menu">
                <result>/menu/Menu.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>  

    <include file="manning/chapterTwo/chapterTwo.xml"/>
    <include file="manning/chapterThree/chapterThree.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterThree/objectBacked/chapterThree.xml"/>
    <include file="manning/chapterThree/modelDriven/chapterThree.xml"/>
    <include file="manning/chapterFour/chapterFour.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterFive/chapterFive.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterSix/chapterSix.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterSeven/chapterSeven.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterEight/chapterEight.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterNine/chapterNine.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterTen/chapterTen.xml"/>  
    <include file="manning/chapterEleven/chapterEleven.xml"/>  


</struts>
```

Why i am getting the error. I have removed some configuration regarding spring in web.xml

Comment: You should read readme.txt file supplied with the code.

Comment: You're getting the error because you removed some configuration regarding Spring in `web.xml` but the app is still trying to use Spring. Also, that filter is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter to below

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
```

And remove struts2-spring-plugin-*.jar from classpath if you have this jar in your classpath and dont want to use Spring integration with Struts2

Please let me know if you still face issue